# Running the Azure Webjobs Dashboard Locally

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I'm wanting to run the Azure Webjobs dashboard locally on our own server to track a task using the webjob framework that isn't running in Azure (running as a service on a local machine).

Previously there was a website project in the azure-webjobs-sdk repository but since moving to .NET Standard 2.0, the dashboard project has been deleted.

Where can I find this codebase? Is it decommissioned? Is there an alternative way to achieve my goal of a locally run dashboard?

Comment: You can still find it in the `v2.x` branch, which is still active. But indeed, it was not carried to the v3 code base.

Comment: @DavidEbbo what is the replacement?

Comment: Switched to an actual Answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still find it in the v2.x branch, which is still active. But indeed, it was not carried to the v3 code base.

For 'traditional' WebJobs, there is no current plan to deprecate the dashboard form the v2 branch. So you can continue to run that locally as you did before.

On the other hand, for Azure Functions, the focus is now on App Insights instead of the WebJobs dashboard.